# How to read ANSI encoded .srt files in the right way?

Tags: video, vlc, multimedia, encoding, subtitle

Is there anyway of any media player that I can view Arabic ANSI encoded .srt files in the right way without converting them to UTF-8 encoding ?
I tried VLC, Gnome mplayer and the default Movie player but all of them are viewing the subtitles as question marks or rectangles.

Comment: In VLC there is a default encoding option in Tools -> Preferences -> Subtitles & OSD. Try to choose Windows-1256 or ISO 8859-6 there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change the encoding of a subtitle file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/277565/how-can-i-change-the-encoding-of-a-subtitle-file)